# form button won't submit with backbone.js form

Tags: backbone.js

I'm following along with Ryan Bates backbone.js RailsCast, part II. In it, he's making a raffle application where you can add new names to a list and then pick a random winner. This is the form he uses in the template to submit the new name. However, when I press submit, nothing happens. It doesn't click.

```
<h1>raffler</h1>

<form id="new_entry">
  <input type="text" name="name" id="new_entry_name">
  <input type="submit" value="Add">
</form>

<ul>
<% for entry in @entries.models: %>
  <li><%= entry.get('name') %></li>
<% end %>
</ul>
```

In the view, on the submit event he uses the createEntry function to create a new name

```
 events:
    'submit #new_entry': 'createEntry'

  initialize: ->
    @collection.on('reset', @render, this)

  render: ->
    $(@el).html(@template(entries: @collection))
    this

  createEntry: (event) ->
    event.preventDefault()
    @collection.create name: $('#new_entry_name').val()
```

Any ideas what might be wrong?

Comment: I am not 100% familiar with how backbone works, but your form doesn't have an action on it. Perhaps you're missing the action? How does the form know where to send the data?

Comment: @jmort253 it uses "events" to listen for the 'submit' on the #new_entry and then calls the createEntry function, which is supposed to take the value from the form and update the collection

Comment: Have you checked your Firebug or Console NET tab to see if there is any traffic being sent to the server on click of submit? Also, any errors in the console? Again, I can't be much more help on this one other than maybe decoding error messages from your debugger. :)

Comment: i retyped the same code without making changes and now it's working. This has happened several times with coffee script. I don't understand why anyone would use such a stupid language...i've googled and found other people who've had similar problems. for some reason the white space can get all effed up....

Comment: Wierd. Well, even thought we don't know why, I'm glad you got it figured out. If you do discover what happened, please be sure to come back and answer your own question. :)

Comment: stop using coffeescript.  would you ever write python in c? would you write java in basic? no.  why would you write one language in another?  you're just adding more layers of abstraction and unless you know javascript like your own parents, you're going to run into errors time and time again